# background image do not display on iphone 5

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, stylesheet

when i test website my chrome desktop and mobile emulatation, it still work [image]

But when i check on iphone 5, banner background is not display
[image]

this my css

```
.banner .backImg {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 772px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have a look on https://caniuse.com/#search=background-image.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691599/2017-answer-to-how-to-make-background-image-fixed-on-iphone6/45465045#45465045